# Error.cshtml in a modal pop up in ASP.NET CORE 2.1 (using exception handling middleware)

Tags: asp.net-core, exception

I am using asp.net core exception handling middleware (app.UseExceptionHandler). I have written a code to display user friendly errors in Home Controller in Error action method. I have also written a code in Error.cshtml view to display the content in a modal pop up.

Everything is working as expected. Error.cshtml is loading in a modal pop up. The challenge over here i am facing is that the Error.chtml is redirecting first and then loading a modal pop up.

I am looking for a solution where i can load Error.cshtml in a modal pop up without having it redirected. i.e. on the same page where error is occuring (example: Edit).

If anyone has a suggestion on how to achieve this, that would be great.

For reference, I am doing what Edward has proposed in this thread: https://forums.asp.net/t/2130016.aspx

Thanks

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: For reference, I am doing what Edward has proposed in this thread: https://forums.asp.net/t/2130016.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found

```
var exceptionFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
            if (exceptionFeature != null)
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = exceptionFeature.Error.Message;
                ViewBag.RouteOfException = exceptionFeature.Path;
                ViewBag.Stacktrace = exceptionFeature.Error.StackTrace;
                ViewBag.ViewName = "_ErrorView";
                ViewBag.Header = "Error";
             }
```

add this in the ErrorController. Add the error message to the TempData
   `TempData["ErrorMessage"] = ViewBag.ErrorMessage`

then redirect to the view from where the exception was thrown which will be in 
    `ViewBag.RouteOfException`

then in the originating view:

```
ViewBag.ErrorMessage=TempData["ErrorMessage"] 
@if (ViewBag.ErrorMessage != null)
{
    <partial name="_ModalPopUp" />
}
```